# Looking for pattern suggestion for game that handle multiple touch events , code got messy

Tags: design-patterns

i have mobile game that has section in code that handle user touches 
basically what it dose is :
 1. main function that get the touch
 2. loop in module A all sprites check if the touch coordinates are in the boundary of one of the sprite if yes call function that associates with the action break the loop
 3. the same as 2 with module B
 4. same as 2,3, with module C and so on
 5. in some some parts of the loop there are Boolean indicators that say :
 6. if boolInd1 is true ignore touches from Module A
 7. if boolInd2 is true ignore touches from Module B
and so on and on ... its very long function 
i was wandering if i can disable this function to structured pattern ?

here is the function just to Demonstrate the ugly complexity:

```
void MainGame::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event  *event)
{

    bool FontSignTouched = false; 
    for( auto& touch : touches)
    {
        auto location = touch->getLocation();
         //once the next level button is triggered to show all other touchs are disabled 

        Vector<Node *> ScoreContainerChildren = pScoreContainer->getChildren();
        for (auto iter = ScoreContainerChildren.begin(); iter != ScoreContainerChildren.end(); ++iter) 
        {
            Node *childNode = *iter; 
            if(childNode->getTag() == buttons_tags::SOUND_BT)
            {

                Point thisTouchScoreContainer = pScoreContainer->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch); 
                Sprite* pSoundBT = static_cast<Sprite*>(*iter); 
                if(pSoundBT->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(thisTouchScoreContainer))
                {

                    pScoreContainer->setSoundButtonSpriteFrame(true);
                    break;
                }

            }

            if(childNode->getTag() == buttons_tags::POINTS_CONTAINER_NODE)
            {

                Sprite* pCoinsBT = (Sprite*)childNode->getChildByTag(buttons_tags::COINS_IMG_BT);
                Sprite* pCoinsCountFrameBT = (Sprite*)childNode->getChildByTag(buttons_tags::COINS_COUNT_FRAME);
                Point thisTouchPointsContainerNode = childNode->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch); 

                if(pCoinsBT->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(thisTouchPointsContainerNode))
                {

                    setPopUpWindow();
                    break;
                }


                if(pCoinsCountFrameBT->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(thisTouchPointsContainerNode))
                {

                    setPopUpWindow();
                    break;
                }                
            }

        }
        Vector<Node *> FontSelectionContainerChildren = pFontSelectionContainer->getChildren();
        for (auto iter = FontSelectionContainerChildren.begin(); iter != FontSelectionContainerChildren.end(); ++iter) 
        {
            Node *childNode = *iter; 
            if(childNode->getTag() == sign_tags::LETTER_SIGH)
            {

                Point thisTouchPositionFontSelection = this->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch); 
                Sign* pSign = static_cast<Sign*>(*iter); 
                if(pSign->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(thisTouchPositionFontSelection))
                {

                    Settings::getInstance()->getSoundManager().playEffect(FONT_TO_SOLUTION);
                    pSolutionContainer->setFontSelectionToSulotionFont(pSign);
                    FontSignTouched = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Vector<Node *> thisSelectionChildren = this->getChildren(); 
        if(!FontSignTouched)
        {
            for (auto iter = thisSelectionChildren.begin(); iter != thisSelectionChildren.end(); ++iter) 
            {
                Node *childNode = *iter; 
                if(childNode->getTag() == sign_tags::LETTER_SIGH)
                {
                    Point thisTouchPositionFontSelection = this->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch);  
                    Sign* pSign = static_cast<Sign*>(*iter); 
                    if(pSign->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(thisTouchPositionFontSelection))
                    {

                        Settings::getInstance()->getSoundManager().playEffect(SOLUTION_TO_FONT);
                        pFontSelectionContainer->removeFromMainParantAndSetInSprite(pSign);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(childNode->getTag() == buttons_tags::NEXT_BT)
                {
                    Point thisTouchPositionFontSelection = this->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch);  
                    Sign* pSign = static_cast<Sign*>(*iter); 
                    if(pSign->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(thisTouchPositionFontSelection))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FontSignTouched = false;
        }
    }

}
```